# TextView text justification

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I have a TextView in my project that is showing very big text. I wanted to justify it and used android: justificationMode = "inter_word". It worked fine on the emulator but didn't work on my Xiaomi Redmi 4x. How can I justify text for my phone. Are there any other ways to show big justified text. There is also \ n in the text to create new lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the attribute "**justificationMode**" only works on android running API version 26 or higher

[Use this library to justify text on android running lower than API 26](https://github.com/amilcar-sr/JustifiedTextView)

You can also use [this](https://github.com/ufo22940268/android-justifiedtextview) library it has the most stars on GitHub for text justification in android

Comment: The new one worked but looks terrible. Thank you anyway